# Stuck on "Connecting Steam Account" after switching to Offline Mode

Tags: steam

After enabling Offline Mode in Steam (while offline) it restarts and idles at a dialog box "Connecting Steam Account: ..." Relaunching and rebooting the machine does not work. Neither does supplying an internet connection.

I'm unable to

- Log out / switch user
- View settings or any other window
- Take any action except Exit Steam

One solution is to completely redownload and reinstall Steam, but I'm connected using my phone, and I don't want to have to reinstall the client and consume data unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by moving some Steam files into temporary directories. I picked a few tiny files and folders based on their size, paths, names and, most importantly, last changed dates, thus confident that they will be recreated when the app launches:

- Program Files/Steam/...

  - update_hosts_cached.vdf
  - ssfn`<digits>`
  - GameOverlayUI.exe.log
  - GameOverlayRenderer.log
  - /config/*
  - /appcache

    - /httpcache
    - /stats
    - appinfo.vdf
    - localization.vdf
    - packageinfo.vdf
  - /userdata/*

The next launch allowed me to log in again. It was probably enough to do /userdata/* (why would .log files have any effect on launch) but I'm not about to experiment with it further. Let me know when you try it out.